# Refund some ethers from smart contract and send the rest to an account

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation

Let's say we want to make a transaction of x ether and if (x>20) refund 5% to sender and send rest to the original initial receiver.How can I implement it in smart contract code, and invoke it from console ? should I send ether to contract and receiver's address in data or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a withdraw pattern which is a best practice, it would look something like this. In case it isn't clear, the function is a lot like an ATM.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Refund {

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    event LogDeposit(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogWithdrawal(address receiver, uint amount);

    function withdrawFunds(uint amount) public returns(bool success) {
        require(amount >= balances[msg.sender]);
        LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, amount);
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        return true;
    }

    function () public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint change;
        uint dep;
        if(msg.value > 20) {
            dep = 20;
            change = msg.value - change;
        }
        balances[msg.sender] += dep;
        if(change > 0) balances[msg.sender] += change;
        LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

p.s. Apologies for the formatting. Browser isn't playing nice with SE today.